# Get/Post/Put methods on current logged in user properties - ASP.NET Web API 2 with ajax request jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

So everything works fine I am just not sure if this is the way I am supposed to do it.
Here is an example for changing the shipping address on the currently 
 logged in user.
This is the controller i made:

```
    [Route("addShippingAdress")]
    [HttpPut] 
    public void addAddress([FromBody] string newShippingAdress)
    {
       string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
       db.Users.Find(userId).ShippingAdress = newShippingAdress;
       db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This is the Ajax Request for changing the shipping address:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: 'addShippingAdress',
            method: 'PUT', 
            contentType: 'application/json',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '
                    + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")
            },
            dataType: "text",
            data: JSON.stringify("some new adress"),
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
```

and this is the Ajax request that I use to Log In:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/token',
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: {
                    username: $('#txtUserName').val(),
                    password: $('#txtPassword').val(),
                    grant_type: 'password'
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem("accessToken", response.access_token);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("userName", response.userName);
                    window.location.href = "Data.html";
                },
                error: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                }
            });
```

So to be more specific, in future when I want to get some properties on the logged in user, or change some of the properties on the logged in user like the shipping address in the example i gave you, is this the way I do it? Do i need to send the access token with every Ajax request like this:

```
...
headers: {
'Authorization': 'Bearer '
+ sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")
},
...
```

for every controller that i want to use for the logged in user and then
find the logged in user like:

```
 string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
 var loggedInUser = db.Users.Find(userId);
 loggedInUser... // some logic here
```

Is this the correct way to do it? If so where does the controller reads the access token that I send in the header of the Ajax request? When i send the shipping address in the body the controller can read it with help of the [FromBody] attribute like this:

```
public void addAddress([FromBody] string newShippingAdress)
```

But where does it read the access token I send in the Header?
 I am novice so please have some patience and understanding. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your API project, create a custom authentication filter as follows:

Create a class `TokenAuthenticationFilterAttribute` which inherits from `System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute` class.

Override the `OnAuthorization` method as follows

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    // Read the authorization header from the request
    var auth = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;

    if(auth != null && auth.Scheme.ToLower().Equals("bearer", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // Validate the header value against database

        // If validation fails, send appropriate response
        actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
}
```

Use this filter on your action methods or controller as follows:

```
[Route("addShippingAdress")]
[HttpPut] 
[TokenAuthenticationFilter]
public void addAddress([FromBody] string newShippingAdress)
{
    string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    db.Users.Find(userId).ShippingAdress = newShippingAdress;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. I just have the question, why would i create the TokenAuthenticationFilterAttribute  class and use the [TokenAuthenticationFilter] atrubute instead of just using the [Authorize] attribute  instead.

Comment: Since you are using `Users` table, I am assuming you are using custom authentication logic instead of default provided by aspnet.

Comment: Final question. I assume i can use any of them and it wont make much of a difference or?

Comment: If you are using default authentication mechanism provided by ASP.NET then just `[Authorize]` attribute is sufficient. If you are using both then you may want to check the order of authentication filters. This link may help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98).aspx